# Reduce Skid Mark Alpha Gradually

Tags: unity-game-engine

For my car war game, I have generated skid marks as the car takes a turn.
It's working properly, now after a few seconds passed, I want to reduce its alpha and remove it from the game. I have used trail renderer to generate skid marks.

- what shader do I require to assign to the material?
- which way I can reduce its alpha?

At present, I have used this kind of trail renderer material:

[image]

Now for reducing alpha gradually, I have this kind of code:

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    Material myMaterial = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        // check whether this skid trail has finished
        // (the Wheel script sets the parent to null when the skid finishes)
        if (transform.parent.name == "SkidTrailsDetachedParent")
        {

            // set the start colour
            //Color startCol = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
            //Color startCol = myMaterial.GetColor("_EmisColor");
            Color startCol = myMaterial.GetColor("_TintColor");

            // wait for the persist time
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(persistTime);

            float t = Time.time;

            // fade out the skid mark
            while (Time.time < t + fadeDuration)
            {
                float i = Mathf.InverseLerp(t, t + fadeDuration, Time.time);
                //myMaterial.color = startCol * new Color(1, 1, 1, 1 - i);
                //myMaterial.SetColor("_EmisColor", startCol * new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f - i));
                myMaterial.SetColor("_TintColor", startCol * new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f - i));
                yield return null;
            }

            // the object has faded and is now done so destroy it
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Still, it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

[`TrailRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer.html) has a property named `endColor` that you could set the alpha of the [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) so that the line fades to the end.

```
void Start()
{
    Color noAlphaEndColor = line.endColor;
    line.endColor = new Color(noAlphaEndColor.r, noAlphaEndColor.g, noAlphaEndColor.b, 0.0f);
}

void Update()
{
    if (line.endColor.a < 0.001)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to remove complete skid trail, not just its end part.

Comment: @Siddharth You will have to determine when your trail stops. This will fade the end. Once your tell the system to stop generating new parts of your trail, then you can wait until the last generated part's alpha is 0, then remove the whole game object.

Comment: First I want to make whole skid trail alpha to 0 through animation from 1 to 0 then after I decided to destroy generated skid trail.

Comment: I believe that's what I was thinking as well. You will generate your trail. The alpha of the trail will go from 1 to 0. You then decide when the trail will stop generating new trail. Once the entire trail's alpha is 0, which you can check by checking the last generated piece's alpha, you can remove the game object.

Comment: Basically, I want something related to material modification, not related to trail renderer.